# Joining multiple rows from datatables into arrays

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, datatable

I am creating a datatable from two tables and from that datatable I am trying to call all of ExpDates and all IncDates, then join them together. My code for the call isn't right as each date is being printer numerous times. 
Here is the code

```
 var stringArr = Dt.AsEnumerable().Select(r => r.Field<string>("IncDate")).ToArray();
var stringArr2 = Dt.AsEnumerable().Select(r => r.Field<string>("ExpDate")).ToArray();
```

and to try and join them I am using

```
 var res = stringArr.Concat(stringArr2).ToArray();
```

dates are stored in dd/MM/yyyy format but something isn't right about my call. 
cheers in advance

Comment: Might be helpful to show what you are expecting as output and what you are actually getting

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Dates
{
public string IncDate;
public string ExpDate;
}

    Dates[] result =  Dt.AsEnumerable()
    .Select(r => new Dates{IncDate = r.Field<string>("IncDate"), ExpDate = r.Field<string>("ExpDate") })
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: thank you but it said "AsEnumerable does not exist in the current context"

Comment: well then remove it;)

Comment: it now says "non-invocable member 'select' cannot be used like a method" lol

Comment: ooooppps i've made a terrible mistake check the code now.

Comment: thank you but final query, when I try to add this to my chart it is saying "cannot implicitly convert type '<anonymous type:string IncDate, string ExpDate>[]' to 'string[]'

Comment: Would you know how I can get around this? Sorry to bother you

Comment: Clarification for this would be fantastic. I don't as of yet have a working answer! Any help would be great

Comment: well this will give you an array of class Dates

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this with zip

```
var joinedValues = stringArr.Zip(stringArr2,(l,r)=>new{IncDate = l, ExpDate=r})
```